# http post request difference from firefox and example

Tags: http, post

I'm new bie. 
I need send data to sever by post requet method.
This is example POST:

```
POST /bin/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg,
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

User=Peter+Lee&pw=123456&action=login
```

I read an example about http post method. I try.... but have some problems.

this is my problem:

when i use firefox to see "post request" but it does not like result of example. 
(about struct of request in firefox) It's only Graphic of firefox. I don't knonw have any "new line" between **header** and **body** in this picture. 
(sorry i can't upload picture to here!)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hpo_7GsGHtdzhhajRjbnNQNTQ/view?usp=sharing

Because i use a divice which send per line of **headers** and **body** to server.
Thank you!

Comment: Please post your details here, not as a link to Google Drive. As written, your question makes no sense.

Comment: My english is not good. I edited. I just join this website. If i have any wrong thing, please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's just the way Firefox displays the request headers, it separates the regular headers from the ones that describe the body content, even though they're not actually separate in the request. When I use the Web Developer tool, my display is slightly different from yours:

[image]

It shows the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers in a section titled 
"Request headers from upload stream". Maybe you're using a different version of FF, or different developer tools (maybe you're using Firebug?).

Comment: i'm using version 38.0.1. When i "Edit and Resend"  

In Request Body: 

**
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 15

user=AAA&pw=BBB **

Comment: I'm using 37.0.2. I'll upgrade now and see if it changes.

Comment: OK, I see that when I use `Edit and Resend`. I think it's doing the same thing, separating the headers related to the content from those related to the whole message.

Comment: When i send a request, it includes Headers and Request Body. As i know, they are divided by new line (enter). is it true??

Comment: Yes, the request body is separated by a blank line. But the `Content-type:` and `Content-Length:` headers should be in the headers, before the blank line.

Comment: Is It only display of FF? Thank you for help! I will try 2 ways!

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to explain in my answer. FF is just showing these separately because it's useful to the programmer.