# Can't send variable in http request to php

Tags: php, http

I have a problem with my http request.
I send a http request to server(using firefox):
the 
**requestheader**

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: vi-VN,vi;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost/home1/
Content-Length: 15
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.868084363.1437301524
Connection: keep-alive

**request body**:


 `ip=192.168.1.13`

**This is my code on server:**

if(isset($_POST['ip'])){
        $ip = $_POST["ip"];
        echo getLightStatusById($ip).'&'.getSuccess($ip)."eos";
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
```

I received message:

```
error
```

if i don't have if condition, i received:

```
undefined index...
```

What am i wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: I posted the same question. When i work with my device (esp8266). 
The problem is my device. But this i try on firefox why can't i do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308948/http-post-request-difference-from-firefox-and-example/30340680?noredirect=1#comment48861800_30340680

Comment: I vote to re-open. This question doesn't seem to be about the "undefined index" error. It's more about why the variable is not posted.